# Make install succeeds in terminal command, but failed in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote an shell script to automatically installs Python on my linux, like this:

```
[ ! -d /usr/local/src/python ] && mkdir /usr/local/src/python
[ ! -d /usr/local/python ] && mkdir /usr/local/python
tar -xvpf ~/Python-2.7.3.tgz -C /usr/local/src/
cd /usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.3 && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python && make && make install
```

But it failed and the errors like this:

```
make: *** no rule to make target 'install '. stop.
```

[image]

I find the operation `make` succeeds while `make install` failed, anybody knows how to fix it? Thanks!
Below is the result of

> cat Makefile | grep -B5 -A15 install

```
# time you run the configure script.  Ideally, you can do:
#
#   ./configure
#   make
#   make test
#   make install
#
# If you have a previous version of Python installed that you don't
# want to overwrite, you can use "make altinstall" instead of "make
# install".  Refer to the "Installing" section in the README file for
# additional details.
#
# See also the section "Build instructions" in the README file.

# === Variables set by makesetup ===

MODOBJS=          Modules/threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o
MODLIBS=        $(LOCALMODLIBS) $(BASEMODLIBS)

# === Variables set by configure
VERSION=    2.7
srcdir=     .


CC=     gcc -pthread
--
SHELL=      /bin/sh

# Use this to make a link between python$(VERSION) and python in $(BINDIR)
LN=     ln

# Portable install script (configure doesn't always guess right)
INSTALL=    /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM=${INSTALL}
INSTALL_SCRIPT= ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_DATA=   ${INSTALL} -m 644
# Shared libraries must be installed with executable mode on some systems;
# rather than figuring out exactly which, we always give them executable mode.
# Also, making them read-only seems to be a good idea...
INSTALL_SHARED= ${INSTALL} -m 555

MAKESETUP=      $(srcdir)/Modules/makesetup

# Compiler options
OPT=        -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
BASECFLAGS=  -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS=     $(BASECFLAGS) -g -O2 $(OPT) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
# Both CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS need to contain the shell's value for setup.py to
# be able to build extension modules using the directories specified in the
# environment variables
CPPFLAGS=   -I. -IInclude -I$(srcdir)/Include 
LDFLAGS=    
--
#export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

# Options to enable prebinding (for fast startup prior to Mac OS X 10.3)
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=

# Environment to run shared python without installed libraries
RUNSHARED=       

# Modes for directories, executables and data files created by the
# install process.  Default to user-only-writable for all file types.
DIRMODE=    755
EXEMODE=    755
FILEMODE=   644

# configure script arguments
CONFIG_ARGS=     '--prefix=/usr/local/pythonbvs'


# Subdirectories with code
SRCDIRS=    Parser Grammar Objects Python Modules Mac

# Other subdirectories
SUBDIRSTOO= Include Lib Misc Demo

# Files and directories to be distributed
--
    else \
        $(BLDSHARED) -o $@ $(LIBRARY_OBJS) $(MODLIBS) $(SHLIBS) $(LIBC) $(LIBM) $(LDLAST); \
    fi

libpython$(VERSION).dylib: $(LIBRARY_OBJS)
     $(CC) -dynamiclib -Wl,-single_module $(LDFLAGS) -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-install_name,$(prefix)/lib/libpython$(VERSION).dylib -Wl,-compatibility_version,$(VERSION) -Wl,-current_version,$(VERSION) -o $@ $(LIBRARY_OBJS) $(SHLIBS) $(LIBC) $(LIBM) $(LDLAST); \


libpython$(VERSION).sl: $(LIBRARY_OBJS)
    $(LDSHARED) -o $@ $(LIBRARY_OBJS) $(MODLIBS) $(SHLIBS) $(LIBC) $(LIBM) $(LDLAST)

# Copy up the gdb python hooks into a position where they can be automatically
# loaded by gdb during Lib/test/test_gdb.py
#
# Distributors are likely to want to install this somewhere else e.g. relative
# to the stripped DWARF data for the shared library.
gdbhooks: $(BUILDPYTHON)-gdb.py

SRC_GDB_HOOKS=$(srcdir)/Tools/gdb/libpython.py
$(BUILDPYTHON)-gdb.py: $(SRC_GDB_HOOKS)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(SRC_GDB_HOOKS) $(BUILDPYTHON)-gdb.py

# This rule is here for OPENSTEP/Rhapsody/MacOSX. It builds a temporary
# minimal framework (not including the Lib directory and such) in the current
# directory.
RESSRCDIR=Mac/Resources/framework
$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK): \
        $(LIBRARY) \
        $(RESSRCDIR)/Info.plist
    $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)
    $(CC) -o $(LDLIBRARY) $(LDFLAGS)  -dynamiclib \
        -all_load $(LIBRARY) -Wl,-single_module \
        -install_name $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK) \
        -compatibility_version $(VERSION) \
        -current_version $(VERSION);
    $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE)  \
        $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)/Resources/English.lproj
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(RESSRCDIR)/Info.plist \
        $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Versions/$(VERSION)/Resources/Info.plist
    $(LN) -fsn $(VERSION) $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Versions/Current
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK) $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK)
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/Headers $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Headers
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/Resources $(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)/Resources

# This rule builds the Cygwin Python DLL and import library if configured
# for a shared core library; otherwise, this rule is a noop.
$(DLLLIBRARY) libpython$(VERSION).dll.a: $(LIBRARY_OBJS)
    if test -n "$(DLLLIBRARY)"; then \
--
        -rm -f $(srcdir)/Lib/test/*.py[co]
        -$(TESTPYTHON) $(TESTPROG) $(MEMTESTOPTS)
        $(TESTPYTHON) $(TESTPROG) $(MEMTESTOPTS)

# Install everything
install:     altinstall bininstall maninstall 

# Install almost everything without disturbing previous versions
altinstall:  altbininstall libinstall inclinstall libainstall \
                sharedinstall oldsharedinstall 

# Install shared libraries enabled by Setup
DESTDIRS=   $(exec_prefix) $(LIBDIR) $(BINLIBDEST) $(DESTSHARED)

oldsharedinstall: $(DESTSHARED) $(SHAREDMODS)
        @for i in X $(SHAREDMODS); do \
          if test $$i != X; then \
            echo $(INSTALL_SHARED) $$i $(DESTSHARED)/`basename $$i`; \
            $(INSTALL_SHARED) $$i $(DESTDIR)$(DESTSHARED)/`basename $$i`; \
          fi; \
        done

$(DESTSHARED):
        @for i in $(DESTDIRS); \
        do \
            if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
                echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
                $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
            else    true; \
            fi; \
        done


# Install the interpreter by creating a symlink chain:
#  $(PYTHON) -> python2 -> python$(VERSION))
# Also create equivalent chains for other installed files
bininstall: altbininstall
    -if test -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON) -o -h $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON); \
    then rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON); \
    else true; \
    fi
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python2$(EXE) $(PYTHON))
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python2$(EXE)
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python$(VERSION)$(EXE) python2$(EXE))
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python2-config
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python$(VERSION)-config python2-config)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python-config
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python2-config python-config)
    -test -d $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC) || $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC)/python2.pc
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC); $(LN) -s python-$(VERSION).pc python2.pc)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC)/python.pc
    (cd $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC); $(LN) -s python2.pc python.pc)

# Install the interpreter with $(VERSION) affixed
# This goes into $(exec_prefix)
altbininstall:  $(BUILDPYTHON)
    @for i in $(BINDIR) $(LIBDIR); \
    do \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(BUILDPYTHON) $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python$(VERSION)$(EXE)
    if test -f $(LDLIBRARY); then \
        if test -n "$(DLLLIBRARY)" ; then \
            $(INSTALL_SHARED) $(DLLLIBRARY) $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); \
        else \
            $(INSTALL_SHARED) $(LDLIBRARY) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(INSTSONAME); \
            if test $(LDLIBRARY) != $(INSTSONAME); then \
--
        fi; \
    else    true; \
    fi

# Install the manual page
maninstall:
    @for i in $(MANDIR) $(MANDIR)/man1; \
    do \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/Misc/python.man \
        $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1/python$(VERSION).1

# Install the library
PLATDIR=    plat-$(MACHDEP)
EXTRAPLATDIR= 
EXTRAMACHDEPPATH=
--
        distutils distutils/command distutils/tests $(XMLLIBSUBDIRS) \
        multiprocessing multiprocessing/dummy \
        unittest unittest/test \
        lib-old \
        curses pydoc_data $(MACHDEPS)
libinstall: build_all $(srcdir)/Lib/$(PLATDIR) $(srcdir)/Modules/xxmodule.c
    @for i in $(SCRIPTDIR) $(LIBDEST); \
    do \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    @for d in $(LIBSUBDIRS); \
    do \
        a=$(srcdir)/Lib/$$d; \
        if test ! -d $$a; then continue; else true; fi; \
        b=$(LIBDEST)/$$d; \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$b; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$b"; \
--
    # is not available in configure
    sed -e "s,@EXENAME@,$(BINDIR)/python$(VERSION)$(EXE)," < $(srcdir)/Misc/python-config.in >python-config

# Install the include files
INCLDIRSTOMAKE=$(INCLUDEDIR) $(CONFINCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDEPY) $(CONFINCLUDEPY)
inclinstall:
    @for i in $(INCLDIRSTOMAKE); \
    do \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    @for i in $(srcdir)/Include/*.h; \
    do \
        echo $(INSTALL_DATA) $$i $(INCLUDEPY); \
        $(INSTALL_DATA) $$i $(DESTDIR)$(INCLUDEPY); \
    done
    $(INSTALL_DATA) pyconfig.h $(DESTDIR)$(CONFINCLUDEPY)/pyconfig.h

--
LIBPL=      $(LIBP)/config

# pkgconfig directory
LIBPC=      $(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig

libainstall:    all python-config
    @for i in $(LIBDIR) $(LIBP) $(LIBPL) $(LIBPC); \
    do \
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    @if test -d $(LIBRARY); then :; else \
        if test "$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)" = no-framework; then \
            if test "$(SO)" = .dll; then \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(LDLIBRARY) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL) ; \
            else \
                $(INSTALL_DATA) $(LIBRARY) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/$(LIBRARY) ; \
                $(RANLIB) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/$(LIBRARY) ; \
            fi; \
        else \
            echo Skip install of $(LIBRARY) - use make frameworkinstall; \
        fi; \
    fi
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/config.c $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/config.c
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/python.o $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/python.o
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(srcdir)/Modules/config.c.in $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/config.c.in
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Makefile $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/Makefile
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/Setup $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/Setup
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/Setup.local $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/Setup.local
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/Setup.config $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/Setup.config
    $(INSTALL_DATA) Misc/python.pc $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPC)/python-$(VERSION).pc
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) $(srcdir)/Modules/makesetup $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/makesetup
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) $(srcdir)/install-sh $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/install-sh
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) python-config $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python$(VERSION)-config
    rm python-config
    @if [ -s Modules/python.exp -a \
        "`echo $(MACHDEP) | sed 's/^\(...\).*/\1/'`" = "aix" ]; then \
        echo; echo "Installing support files for building shared extension modules on AIX:"; \
        $(INSTALL_DATA) Modules/python.exp      \
                $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/python.exp;      \
        echo; echo "$(LIBPL)/python.exp";       \
        $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) $(srcdir)/Modules/makexp_aix  \
                $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/makexp_aix;      \
        echo "$(LIBPL)/makexp_aix";         \
        $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) $(srcdir)/Modules/ld_so_aix   \
                $(DESTDIR)$(LIBPL)/ld_so_aix;       \
        echo "$(LIBPL)/ld_so_aix";          \
        echo; echo "See Misc/AIX-NOTES for details.";   \
--
        ;; \
    esac

# Install the dynamically loadable modules
# This goes into $(exec_prefix)
sharedinstall: sharedmods
    $(RUNSHARED) ./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E $(srcdir)/setup.py install \
        --prefix=$(prefix) \
        --install-scripts=$(BINDIR) \
        --install-platlib=$(DESTSHARED) \
        --root=$(DESTDIR)/

# Here are a couple of targets for MacOSX again, to install a full
# framework-based Python. frameworkinstall installs everything, the
# subtargets install specific parts. Much of the actual work is offloaded to
# the Makefile in Mac
#
#
# This target is here for backward compatiblity, previous versions of Python
# hadn't integrated framework installation in the normal install process.
frameworkinstall: install

# On install, we re-make the framework
# structure in the install location, /Library/Frameworks/ or the argument to
# --enable-framework. If --enable-framework has been specified then we have
# automatically set prefix to the location deep down in the framework, so we
# only have to cater for the structural bits of the framework.

frameworkinstallframework: frameworkinstallstructure install frameworkinstallmaclib

frameworkinstallstructure:  $(LDLIBRARY)
    @if test "$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR)" = no-framework; then \
        echo Not configured with --enable-framework; \
        exit 1; \
    else true; \
    fi
    @for i in $(prefix)/Resources/English.lproj $(prefix)/lib; do\
        if test ! -d $(DESTDIR)$$i; then \
            echo "Creating directory $(DESTDIR)$$i"; \
            $(INSTALL) -d -m $(DIRMODE) $(DESTDIR)$$i; \
        else    true; \
        fi; \
    done
    $(LN) -fsn include/python$(VERSION) $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/Headers
    sed 's/%VERSION%/'"`$(RUNSHARED) ./$(BUILDPYTHON) -c 'import platform; print platform.python_version()'`"'/g' < $(RESSRCDIR)/Info.plist > $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/Resources/Info.plist
    $(LN) -fsn $(VERSION) $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/Versions/Current
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK) $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK)
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/Headers $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/Headers
    $(LN) -fsn Versions/Current/Resources $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR)/Resources
    $(INSTALL_SHARED) $(LDLIBRARY) $(DESTDIR)$(PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX)/$(LDLIBRARY)

# This installs Mac/Lib into the framework
# Install a number of symlinks to keep software that expects a normal unix
# install (which includes python-config) happy.
frameworkinstallmaclib:
    ln -fs "../../../$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK)" "$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib/python$(VERSION)/config/libpython$(VERSION).a"
    ln -fs "../../../$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK)" "$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib/python$(VERSION)/config/libpython$(VERSION).dylib"
    ln -fs "../$(PYTHONFRAMEWORK)" "$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/lib/libpython$(VERSION).dylib"
    cd Mac && $(MAKE) installmacsubtree DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)"

# This installs the IDE, the Launcher and other apps into /Applications
frameworkinstallapps:
    cd Mac && $(MAKE) installapps DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)"

# This install the unix python and pythonw tools in /usr/local/bin
frameworkinstallunixtools:
    cd Mac && $(MAKE) installunixtools DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)"

frameworkaltinstallunixtools:
    cd Mac && $(MAKE) altinstallunixtools DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)"

# This installs the Demos and Tools into the applications directory.
# It is not part of a normal frameworkinstall
frameworkinstallextras:
    cd Mac && $(MAKE) installextras DESTDIR="$(DESTDIR)"

# This installs a few of the useful scripts in Tools/scripts
scriptsinstall:
    SRCDIR=$(srcdir) $(RUNSHARED) \
    ./$(BUILDPYTHON) $(srcdir)/Tools/scripts/setup.py install \
    --prefix=$(prefix) \
    --install-scripts=$(BINDIR) \
    --root=$(DESTDIR)/

# Build the toplevel Makefile
Makefile.pre: Makefile.pre.in config.status
    CONFIG_FILES=Makefile.pre CONFIG_HEADERS= $(SHELL) config.status
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.pre Makefile

# Run the configure script.
config.status:  $(srcdir)/configure
    $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/configure $(CONFIG_ARGS)

.PRECIOUS: config.status $(BUILDPYTHON) Makefile Makefile.pre

# Some make's put the object file in the current directory
.c.o:
--

Python/thread.o:  $(srcdir)/Python/thread_atheos.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_beos.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_cthread.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_foobar.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_lwp.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_nt.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_os2.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_pth.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_pthread.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_sgi.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_solaris.h $(srcdir)/Python/thread_wince.h

# Declare targets that aren't real files
.PHONY: all build_all sharedmods oldsharedmods test quicktest memtest
.PHONY: install altinstall oldsharedinstall bininstall altbininstall
.PHONY: maninstall libinstall inclinstall libainstall sharedinstall
.PHONY: frameworkinstall frameworkinstallframework frameworkinstallstructure
.PHONY: frameworkinstallmaclib frameworkinstallapps frameworkinstallunixtools
.PHONY: frameworkaltinstallunixtools recheck autoconf clean clobber distclean 
.PHONY: smelly funny patchcheck
.PHONY: gdbhooks

# IF YOU PUT ANYTHING HERE IT WILL GO AWAY

# Rules appended by makedepend

Modules/threadmodule.o: $(srcdir)/Modules/threadmodule.c; $(CC) $(PY_CFLAGS)  -c $(srcdir)/Modules/threadmodule.c -o Modules/threadmodule.o
Modules/threadmodule$(SO):  Modules/threadmodule.o; $(BLDSHARED)  Modules/threadmodule.o   -o Modules/threadmodule$(SO)
Modules/signalmodule.o: $(srcdir)/Modules/signalmodule.c; $(CC) $(PY_CFLAGS)  -c $(srcdir)/Modules/signalmodule.c -o Modules/signalmodule.o
Modules/signalmodule$(SO):  Modules/signalmodule.o; $(BLDSHARED)  Modules/signalmodule.o   -o Modules/signalmodule$(SO)
Modules/posixmodule.o: $(srcdir)/Modules/posixmodule.c; $(CC) $(PY_CFLAGS)  -c $(srcdir)/Modules/posixmodule.c -o Modules/posixmodule.o
Modules/posixmodule$(SO):  Modules/posixmodule.o; $(BLDSHARED)  Modules/posixmodule.o   -o Modules/posixmodule$(SO)
Modules/errnomodule.o: $(srcdir)/Modules/errnomodule.c; $(CC) $(PY_CFLAGS)  -c $(srcdir)/Modules/errnomodule.c -o Modules/errnomodule.o
Modules/errnomodule$(SO):  Modules/errnomodule.o; $(BLDSHARED)  Modules/errnomodule.o   -o Modules/errnomodule$(SO)
```

Comment: Without seeing the errors on the lines before, no, we have no idea.

Comment: Tangential hint: `mkdir -p /usr/local/src/python /usr/local/python`

Comment: cat Makefile | grep -B5 -A15 install

Comment: There is some invalid character after 'make install'. Most likely a \r (0x0d)

Comment: Thanks to @LorinczyZsigmond, I wrote this shell script on Windows, when I put it on Linux, although I used the command `dos2unix` but it still has \r. When I delete the \r , it works.